# Ruby on Rails: how do I sort with two columns using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to sort by two columns, one is a DateTime (`updated_at`), and the other is a Decimal (Price)

I would like to be able to sort first by updated_at, then, if multiple items occur on the same day, sort by Price.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL,

```
Model.all(:order => 'DATE(updated_at), price')
```

Note the distinction from the other answers. The `updated_at` column will be a full timestamp, so if you want to sort based on the **day** it was updated, you need to use a function to get just the date part from the timestamp. In MySQL, that is [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Comment: To stop joins from randomly breaking with "ambiguous column" messages, you should use the following more robust version: `:order => ["DATE(#{table_name}.updated_at)", :price]` (Note that `:price` is a symbol.)

Comment: I had to escape my order column with `order` like so: ```Model.all(:order => "day asc, `order` asc")```

Answer (score 182):

In Rails 4 you can do something similar to:

```
Model.order(foo: :asc, bar: :desc)
```

`foo` and `bar` are columns in the db.

Answer (score 69):

```
Thing.find(:all, :order => "updated_at desc, price asc")
```

will do the trick.

### Update:

```
Thing.all.order("updated_at DESC, price ASC")
```

is the Rails 3 way to go. (Thanks [@cpursley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825383/cpursley))

Comment: Thank you @Erik - I know this answer is old so here's my warning for those seeing it now: This method has been deprecated starting Rails 3.2. Use Thing.all instead =)

Comment: Correct, this worked well for me:

`Thing.all.order("updated_at DESC, price ASC")`

Comment: Your update was helpful for me when I needed to lowercase the sorted values: `Thing.order("LOWER(name), number")`.

Comment: The update here enabled me to order on an association after ordering on a direct attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

[Active Record Query Interface](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) lets you specify as many attributes as you want to [order](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) your query:

```
models = Model.order(:date, :hour, price: :desc)
```

or if you want to get more specific (thanks [@zw963](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749774/zw963) ):

```
models = Model.order(price: :desc, date: :desc, price: :asc)
```

Bonus: After the first query, you can chain other queries:

```
models = models.where('date >= :date', date: Time.current.to_date)
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'd personally change `model` to `models` so that a person would know it's pluralized. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I think should edit a more specially example: e.g.  models = Model.order({price: :desc}, {date: :desc}, {price: asc})

Comment: if anyone pasted this and saw undefined method error, there's a small typo here. It should be `:asc` instead of `asc`: `Model.order({price: :desc}, {date: :desc}, {price: 
:asc}) `

Answer (score 20):

Actually there are many ways to do it using Active Record. One that has not been mentioned above would be (in various formats, all valid):

```
Model.order(foo: :asc).order(:bar => :desc).order(:etc)
```

Maybe it's more verbose, but personally I find it easier to manage.
SQL gets produced in one step only:

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models" ORDER BY "models"."etc" ASC, "models"."bar" DESC, "models"."foo" ASC
```

Thusly, for the original question:

```
Model.order(:updated_at).order(:price)
```

You need not declare data type, ActiveRecord does this smoothly, and so does your DB Engine

Comment: This works great when using two columns from two different tables like: 
Member.includes(:voter).order("town_club asc").order("voters.last_name asc")

Comment: Does the SQL you posted correspond to `Model.order(foo: :asc).order(:bar => :desc).order(:etc)`? The order of the order clauses in the SQL is the opposite of what I get when I run `.to_sql` on that.

Comment: @Qaz this is a long time ago. I think I probably need to correct this one, I'd never noticed. I'll double check later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Model.all(:order => 'updated_at, price')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do only separating with commas like this

```
.where(your query).order("name desc, status asc")
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me! 
After exactly 2 days of looking top and bottom over the internet, I found a solution!!

lets say you have many columns in the products table including: special_price and msrp. These are the two columns we are trying to sort with.

Okay, First in your Model
add this line:

```
named_scope :sorted_by_special_price_asc_msrp_asc, { :order => 'special_price asc,msrp asc' }
```

Second, in the Product Controller, add where you need to perform the search:

```
@search = Product.sorted_by_special_price_asc_msrp_asc.search(search_params)
```