# Efficient sorting of rows by multiple columns in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table name transactions with following columns

```
created_at        | debit | credit | balance | account_id
2012-2-2 02:22:22 | 3000  | 0      | 0       | 8
2012-2-2 07:22:22 | 500   | 1000   | 0       | 8
2012-2-2 09:22:22 | 0     | 8000   | 0       | 8

2012-3-3 19:17:20 | 1000  | 0      | 0       | 8
2012-3-3 04:02:22 | 0     | 8000   | 0       | 8
```

Before calculating balance I need to

- sort transactions by date (i.e. daily)
- then sort by debit (higher debit must come first)

I have a million transactions distinguished by account_id. What is efficient way of sorting in such a scenario ?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but wouldn't sorting by time on each date be the same as sorting by time? If you sort by time first, then any secondary sort won't really matter, unless two transactions happened exactly at the same time. Maybe you mean sort by date, then by debit?

Comment: Try grouping by date and sort by debit.

Comment: @operand: Yes I mean by date :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord)

```
Transaction.all(:order => "created_at DESC, debit DESC")
```

This kind of querying is exactly what relational databases are good at and with proper indexing, it should be efficient for you.

For a particular account…

```
Transaction.find_by_account_id(some_id, :order => "created_at DESC, debit DESC")
```

If this is setup as a proper ActiveRecord association on the account, you can set the order there so the association is always returned in the preferred order:

```
class Account
    has_many :transactions, :order => "created_at DESC, debit DESC"
end
```

This way, any time you ask an account for its transactions like `Account.find(12345).transactions` they'll be returned in the preferred sorting automatically.

Comment: I know this answer was posted in 2012, but to contribute to people who may need, I'll post here a way to do it in Rails 4.0+, since `:order` in `has_many` block has been deprecated and needs to be replaced with lambda scope block. You can do it using `hash` style: `has_many :transactions, -> { order(created_at: :desc, debit: desc) }`, or still as `string`: `has_many :transactions, -> { order('created_at DESC, debit DESC') }`