# Rails how to sort based on "last activity" using a model and it's has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
Question:
   has_many: answers

Answer:
   belongs_to: question
```

How can I `select all questions` ordering based on "last activity" which would be the question.created_at or answer.created_at

**Examples:**

If an old question just got a new **answer**, it would be the first one on the list.

If a new question just got posted, it would be the first one on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another field for questions which would be  set to the current time each time a new answer is added to the question.The initial value should be set same as created at.then sort them based on this column

Comment: That's nice quick solution. Thanks! I eventually decided to go with creating a full blown activity polymorphic association.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

Make scope in Question Model

```
scope :sorted_questions, order("id DESC")
scope :sorted_answers, order("answers.created_at DESC")
scope :final_sorted, order("id DESC, answers.created_at DESC")
```

Then try this:

```
@questions = Question.sorted_answers
index = 0
@quesions.each do |question|
  if question.id != Quesion.sorted_questions[index].id
     index++
  else
     break
  end
end
@questions << Quesion.sorted_questions[0...index]
```

or Try this:

```
@questions = Question.final_sorted
```

[Efficient sorting of rows by multiple columns in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068836/efficient-sorting-of-rows-by-multiple-columns-in-rails-3)

Comment: I get an error in QL syntax... `'&:create_at)) DESC, id DESC' at line 1`

Comment: New questions end up at the bottom of the list with this :(

Comment: I think I might need to create a full blown activity model to accomplish this.

Comment: I think you are right :)
if i reach to more easy query, i'll edit my answer
but, I edit my answer now as short method as possible