# Ruby/RoR, ActiveRecord - "arrange" method and use "super" in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, super

System

```
[2017-11-13 18:34:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-11-13 18:34:46] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-linux]
```

Model in Ror, that working (currenct version)

```
class Expenditure < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  class << self
    def arrange
      super(:order => :name)
    end
...
```

I tried to add one more field for change order way. "**sort_order**".
I cannot find method `arrange` in ActiveRecord, which was redifyned
I have tried unsuccesfully

```
super(:order => :sort_order, :name)
```

...

```
super.order(:sort_order, :name)
```

Comment: which attributes do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: I whant add "sort_order" before "name" ordering, now I have end of query like this: `... ORDER BY (case when expenditures.ancestry is null then 0 else 1 end), expenditures.ancestry, name`, that is why I have to stay use super

Comment: I have no Idia, where is `arrange` method from

Answer (score 0):

`arrange` method from [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem. It's https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/blob/8482196e32ac46a9d89c5e3b2d7080e4b830b1d0/lib/ancestry/class_methods.rb#L31

```
    # Arrangement
    def arrange options = {}
      # Get all nodes ordered by ancestry and start sorting them into an empty hash
      arrange_nodes self.ancestry_base_class.reorder(options.delete(:order)).where(options)
    end
```

Comment: I don't understand, how can I send two parameters for sorting. Parameters seems like Hahs, But didn't work like `(:order => :sort_order, :order => :name)` or `({:order=>:sort_order, :order=>:name})'

Comment: you can do this with `:order => "sort_order ASC, name ASC"` 
 .More examples you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord

Comment: Yes, That is it. Thank you very match. `super(:order => "sort_order, name")`. Your link was very usefull

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question properly, but I think you wanted to use `self` (not `super` 'cause there is no `arrange` method defined in AR) with `order` method. If you want to order it by `sort_order` and `name` in ascending order your method should look like this:

```
def arrange
  self.order(:sort_order => :asc, :name => :asc)
end
```

you can even omit `self` and just use `self.order(:sort_order => :asc, :name => :asc)`

Comment: No, I need `super`