# How to bring pinned post on top of the feed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on rails api, and I have many posts that belong to users. They have been arranged by `{created_at: : desc}`. Each post has `pinned` field. Is it possible to bring the post where `pinned: true` on top of the feed (and where other records are still arranged by created_at order)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: how do I sort with two columns using ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change ordering, so if `{created_at: :desc}` is default scope and you need `pinned` ordering only once use `reorder`

```
reorder(pinned: :desc, created_at: :desc)
```

If you need this order always you can change your default order on

```
order(pinned: :desc, created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that it didn't work for me when I tried this way because I was putting ```created_at: :desc``` before ```:pinned :desc```.